# How can I distinguish a String(of characters) leading a minus sign in JAVA? ex: "buy" and "-buy"

Tags: java, string, signed

I am comparatively new in JAVA. I am implementing an idea involving multimap. Now I want to put "buy" and "-buy" as the key. My question is, how can I distinguish that the original string(characters) is same but they have opposing leading sign???

Comment: What kind of behavior would you like? Can you give an example of how you would like the data to be set and how you would like it to be retrieved?

Comment: You need to explain better what you want.

Comment: I can tell you the behavior that I want. I want my multimap to distinguish between "buy" and "-buy" to keys as same strings/values with opposing signs. I am making an expert system. Want the interpreter to understand, whatever key="buy" is saying, key="-buy" is saying something opposite.

Comment: You can always compare the length of string. If the length differ by 1 then prepend "-" to smaller string and then compare both the strings.

Comment: more precisely, it can work like: String.quals(String) for the string value while understanding the opposing leading sign. The interpreter will be able to distinguish: "buy" and "-buy" and "x" and "-x" as OPPOSITES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misusing the concept of multimaps. I am gathering from your question that you want to look up a single key and have it return values for two keys (with and without '-' before them). Multimaps don't support multiple keys (as far as I'm aware in any case). They support multiple values for each key.

You have a number of options:

1. Don't encode the 'opposite' semantic in the key. Rather create a new class with the String and a boolean field for flagging opposite and use that class as your key.

   public class Operation {
       String getName();
       Boolean isOpposite();
   }

   Map> map;
2. Don't include the logic on opposites in the data structure at all. Rather parse the key on usage. In other words you would need to `get` both "buy" and "-buy" as keys and then sort out what to do with each in your code.
3. Make your `Map` two levels with the second level representing whether the values are opposite or not:

   `Map<String,Map<Boolean,List<Value>>> map;`

   `map.get("buy").get(true)...`

The first option is definitely the best in my view. The text associated with the values should just be one attribute of your key - if you end up having to add others then you will end up with a bunch of logic encoded in the key.

Answer (score 0):

To have a map with multiple values for a single *key*, where `key="buy"` and `key="-buy"`, I’d recommend using the `MultiValueMap` from the [Apache Commons Collection library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections). The Javadoc for the `MultiValueMap` is [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html).